# Cannot create ResourceGroup using boto3: Query format not valid

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am trying to create a resource group using the following boto3 snippet:

```
kwargs = {
    'Name': 'cluster.foo.io',
    'Description': 'AWS resources assigned to the foo cluster.',
    'ResourceQuery': {
        'Type': 'TAG_FILTERS_1_0',
        'Query': '[{"Key": "foo.io/cluster", "Values": ["cluster.foo.io"]}]',
    },
    'Tags': {
        'foo.io/cluster': 'cluster.foo.io'
    }
}

client = boto3.client("resource-groups")
resp = client.create_group(**kwargs)
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
File "/Users/benjamin/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
File "/Users/benjamin/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 661, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.BadRequestException: An error occurred (BadRequestException) 
    when calling the CreateGroup operation: Query not valid: 
    Query format not valid: check JSON syntax
```

I keep comparing the Query to the [example in the documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/resource-groups.html#ResourceGroups.Client.create_group) but either I'm not seeing a difference or I'm way off in left field. I even used the `json` module as follows:

```
resp = self.resource_client.create_group(
    Name='cluster.foo.io',
    Description="AWS resources assigned to the foo cluster",
    ResourceQuery={
        "Type": "TAG_FILTERS_1_0",
        "Query": json.dumps([{"Key": "foo.io/cluster", "Values": ["cluster.foo.io"]}]),
    },
    Tags={
        "foo.io/cluster": "cluster.foo.io",
    },
)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query parameter is missing ResourceTypeFilters and TagFilters. So, ResourceQuery should look like this:

```
'ResourceQuery': {
    'Type': 'TAG_FILTERS_1_0',
    'Query': "{\"ResourceTypeFilters\": [\"AWS::AllSupported\"], \"TagFilters\": [{\"Key\": \"foo.io/cluster\", \"Values\": [\"cluster.foo.io\"]}]}"
}
```

So, your code should be replaced as follows (the main section to be replaced is ResourceQuery:

```
query = {
    "ResourceTypeFilters": ["AWS::AllSupported"],
    "TagFilters": [{
        "Key": "foo.io/cluster",
        "Values": ["cluster.foo.io"]
    }]
}
resource_query = {
    'Type': 'TAG_FILTERS_1_0',
    'Query': json.dumps(query)
}
kwargs = {
    'Name': 'cluster.foo.io',
    'Description': 'AWS resources assigned to the foo cluster.',
    'ResourceQuery': resource_query,
    'Tags': {
        'foo.io/cluster': 'cluster.foo.io'
    }
}
client = boto3.client("resource-groups")
resp = client.create_group(**kwargs)
```

I referred the example CLI shown [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/resource-groups/create-group.html).